# Why numba raise a type error in numpy linspace

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I am using `numba` 0.34.0 and `numpy` 1.13.1. A small example is shown as following:

```
import numpy as np    
from numba import jit
@jit(nopython=True)
def initial(veh_size):
    t = np.linspace(0, (100 - 1) * 30, 100, dtype=np.int32)
    t0 = np.linspace(0, (veh_size - 1) * 30, veh_size, dtype=np.int32)
    return t0

initial(100)
```

Both the line with `t` and `t0` have the same error message.

The error message:

> ```
> numba.errors.InternalError: 
> [1] During: resolving callee type: Function(<function linspace at 0x000001F977678C80>)
> [2] During: typing of call at ***/test1.py (6)
> ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the numba version of `np.linspace` accepts no `dtype` argument ([source: numba 0.34 documentation](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.34.0/reference/numpysupported.html#other-functions)):

> ## 2.7.3.3. Other functions
>
> The following top-level functions are supported:
>
> - [...]
> - `numpy.linspace()` (only the 3-argument form)
> - [...]

You need to use `astype` to convert it inside a nopython-numba function:

```
import numpy as np    
from numba import jit
@jit(nopython=True)
def initial(veh_size):
    t = np.linspace(0, (100 - 1) * 30, 100).astype(np.int32)
    t0 = np.linspace(0, (veh_size - 1) * 30, veh_size).astype(np.int32)
    return t0

initial(100)
```

Or just don't use `np.linspace` in nopython-numba functions and pass it in as argument. That avoids a temporary array and I doubt that numbas `np.linspace` is faster than NumPys.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I did not check the `numba` and simply thought it should fully support `linspace`.

Comment: You're welcome. I often wished numbas exceptions were a **bit** more helpful - but currently one has to refer to the numba documentation if one encounters weird `TypingError`s (as regular numba user I already bookmarked the supported features pages). :)

Comment: Yes, I have the same feeling. `numba` 's error message is not easy to follow as `python` or `numpy`. It courses confusing how the error happens.